# How can I find the number of CALs for Dynamics CRM 4.0

Tags: microsoft-dynamics-crm

I have two questions, which are as follows:-

1. How can I find the number of CALs for Dynamics CRM 4.0? Lets consider the situation that we don't have license certificates that we got when we purchase Dynamics CRM 4.0.
2. Right now, I check the deployment manager and got this information that we have Enterprise license, is this the right way to check which server license we have?

Looking forward to hear from you. Many thanks.

Comment: The number of CALs that you are actively consuming, or the number of CAL packs already inputted to the license system?

Comment: Looking for both, the # of CALs we are consuming right away and # of CALs packs already inputted in the license system.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, and this should also show you how many client licenses (CALs) you have.